# awk: how to interpret/read the below command (how this command works)

Tags: awk

**Could someone please help understand how to interpret/read this awk command?**

```
awk '/foo/{if (a ~ /abc/) print a; print} {a=$0}' file
```

**For a file with lines:**

```
abc 0
def
abc 1
foo 1
ghi
jkl
foo 2
foo 3
mno
abc 2
foo 4
foo 5`
```

**Observed that the command prints the output as:**

```
abc 1
foo 1
foo 2
foo 3
abc 2
foo 4
foo 5`
```

Comment: It's time for you to work thru an `awk` tutorial. (This is very basic stuff AND off-topic for StackOverflow). Check out http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html . Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

> Could someone please help understand how to interpret/read this awk
>   command?
>
> ```
> awk '/foo/{if (a ~ /abc/) print a; print} {a=$0}' file
> ```

In short what above command does is, it searches for line which contains `foo`, if line found then then it checks whether previous read line (`variable a`) has `abc`, if true then, it prints previous line `(that is variable a contents; print a)`, and then print current line (`line which contains "foo"; print`).

***Explanation as follows:***

```
awk '                               # call awk
     /foo/{                         # if line/record/row contains "foo" then

                if (a ~ /abc/)      # if variable a contains "abc" then 
                          print a;  # print contents of variable a
                print               # print current record/row/line
          } 
          {
                a=$0                # save current record/line/row in variable a
          }
    ' file                          # here you read file
```